# Finding the last occurence in a given pattern

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a huge log-file where some lines start with `Step`, some start with `Test done:`, and some start with neither.

For each of the `Test done:` lines, I want to extract everything since the last `Step` line.

So, for example, if this is the log-file:

```
Step 1: Do Blah
Value of blah is 1
Step 2: Do blah blah
Value of blah blah is 2
Step 3: "foo bar baz"
Value of baz is 3
Test done: dummy1 failed
Step 4 :Verify, blah blah blah
NODE-1# ls -l
testcase failed
Test done: dummy_2 failed
```

then I want to extract this:

```
Step 3: "foo bar baz"
Value of baz is 3
Test done: dummy1 failed
```

and this:

```
Step 4 :Verify, blah blah blah
NODE-1# ls -l
testcase failed
Test done: dummy_2 failed
```

I tried the Perl regex `(Step(?!Step.*).*?Test done)`, but it didn't get the intended results.

Comment: What did you try? Show your code.

Comment: (Step(?!Step.*).*?Test done)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say that the log-file is "huge", it's probably not a good idea to read the whole thing into a single Perl string.

Instead, I recommend iterating over the lines, and keeping track of all lines since the latest `Step` line:

```
my @lines_to_print = ();
while (<>) {
    if (m/^Step/) {
        @lines_to_print = ();
    }
    push @lines_to_print, $_;
    if (m/^Test done:/) {
        print @lines_to_print;
    }
}
```

But if you still prefer the regex approach, you can read the file into a string, and then write:

```
m/^Step.*\n(?>(?:(?!Step|Test done:).*\n)*)Test done:.*\n/gm;
```

to capture any occurrence of a line that starts with `Step`, plus zero or more lines that do *not* start with `Step` or `Test done:`, plus a line that starts with `Test done:`.

Note that in both of the above approaches, I didn't worry about the behavior if the first `Test done:` line comes before the first `Step` line, or if there are two `Test done:` lines without a `Step` line between them, since it seemed that that's not possible? If that *is* possible, and if the behavior in that case matters, let me know and I can tweak the above.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you want, show use what you've tried so far next time, it helps understanding. But still, lets try something!

Since you thought of perl to do this, and perl is quite good at doing stuff with files and regex, lets use perl.

Assuming you read your file into a single string `$string`, you can do something like that :

```
$string =~ m/.*(Step.*?Test done[^\n]*)/s
```

Explanations :
`.*` is a *greedy* quantifier, it's gonna try to match the longest string it can.
`.*?` is the same as .*, but *nongreedy*.
`[^\n]` will match anything but `\n` (newline).
`s` modifier allows `.` to match newlines.
So if I explain the regex with a sentence : find the longest string preceding *Step* followed by the fewer characters possible until you find *Test done*. And returns all the text between that *Step* and *Test done*, plus all the text on the end of the *Test done* line.

The result you want will then be in `$1`.

Comment: Hi Dada, I wanted to extract all the text starting from "Step 3 until  "Test done: dummy1 failed".

Comment: The answer you suggested gives all the text till  Test done: dummy_2 failed, which is  the second instance. I want to stop matching at the first instance of Test done itself.

Comment: Ok, your *last* Step and *first* Test done got me confused. (And I think there are more than one way to understand it)  
Use that regex instead then : m/.*?(Step(?:(?!Step).)*?Test done[^\n]*)/s  
You should have a look at that great article : http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444

Comment: Thankyou, this has helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple, just use awk:

```
$ awk '/^Step/{buf=""} {buf = buf $0 ORS} /^Test done/{print buf}' file      
Step 3: "foo bar baz"
Value of baz is 3
Test done: dummy1 failed

Step 4 :Verify, blah blah blah
NODE-1# ls -l
testcase failed
Test done: dummy_2 failed
```